# Getting Value Through C# Getter Setter Property Returns Null

Tags: c#, null, setter, getter

I have a `Login.cs` class and I have set properties in it as below.

```
private string Username_;
private string Password_; 

public string UserName
{
    get => Username_;
    set => Username_ = value; 
}
public string Password
{
    get => Password_; 
    set => Password_ = value; 
}
```

and setting the values in the same class for both properties as below.

```
UserName = "admin";
Password = "admin";
```

Where `Username_` & `Password_` are both `string`s. Now I have another `Usercontrol` which I am accessing in `MainWindow` on button click which is shown below.

```
<vm:ViewUsers x:Name="ViewAllUsers" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

What I am doing in Code behind of UserControl is as below to access the values of `Username` and `Password` through `Property Getter Setter` as below.

```
string username = Login.GetInstance().UserName;
string password = Login.GetInstance().Password;
```

On debugging `obj.UserName;` property Returns Null. Why does it return null and how should I fix that?

Comment: You never really set the value for Username_ to anyting. Try `Username_ = "foo";`in your class.

Comment: If the returned value is null, then the value of the backing field *is* null *at the time* the get-accessor is invoked.. start with that premise and work backwards: What makes it true? Why is the backing field [still] null? Use the debugger as needed as to step through the execution and test hypothesis (and update incorrect assumptions).

Comment: Your property is not mapped to any user control & not setting value in code too

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're creating a new instance of `Login()` before you fetch the properties:

```
// Code originally in the question
Login obj = new Login();
```

This has now been changed to `Login.GetInstance()`, but we don't know what that method does. If *that* method returns a reference to a new instance of `Login` each time, we're left with the same problem.

Both properties in that object *will* be null, because you haven't set them to anything. (The default value for all reference types is null.) It's not clear to me where you're setting the properties to any other value, but whichever object you're setting them on isn't the same one that you're then using in the final piece of code you showed us.

You need to make sure you can use the "getters" on the same object that you called the "setters" on.

As an aside, because your properties are trivial (they're just getting and setting variables, with no other behavior such as validation) you can replace *all* of the first piece of code you've got with automatically implemented properties:

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: Well, I have set the Properties as Username = "Admin" and Password = "Admin" and called the Login.GetInstance().UserName; but it still returns Null.

Comment: @asim.ali314: *Where* have you set those properties though? Which object have you set them on? What is `Login.GetInstance()`? (You haven't shown us that.) Whatever reference that returns, `new Login()` will create a separate, independent instance with its own properties.

Comment: Please refer to the question I have made some changing and edited the existing one. As I am new to C# so please I need detailed examples if possible with some code snippets.

Comment: @asim.ali314: We still don't know what `Login.GetInstance()` does. I understand that at the moment these answers may not be helping much, but Stack Overflow isn't a great way of learning the basics of the language, and even providing code to fix the immediate problem probably wouldn't help much in terms of future work. I'd strongly encourage you to get hold of a good C# book and read it really carefully. It's super important to understand how the type system works - what objects are, the differences between reference types and value types etc.

Comment: @asim.ali314: I'd argue that it's easier to learn a lot of those early concepts using console applications instead of GUIs, as you can write a whole program in a much smaller amount of code, without a lot of background "magic" going on which often takes place in GUIs.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding how getters and setters work I think.

At the moment of initialization of an object, all it's uninitialized fields are set to default values (`null` for reference types, 0 for numbers, etc.).

Getters and setters are, as their name suggest, for setting value and getting.

What you are doing, after initialization you use private fields to supply value for respective setter. But what it does is assign value supplied to it to underlaying field.

Since you are using the same private field, you never initialize it, since it is `null` (as I mentioned), then you try to set its value through setter, but what you pass there is `null`, hence you end up with `null`s as well.

And C# provide something known as properties, so you don't need private fields. Unless you want to develop some additional logic for getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

As other users have stated, you are creating a new instance of Login which automatically initializes the fields to default values (null for reference types, 0 for numbers).

Also, you can look at removing the default constructor for Login class and have the following as constructor:

```
public Login(string username, string password)
{
    Username = username;
    Password = password;
}
```

By doing this, you can then do `Login login = new Login("admin", "admin")`.

You can also look at **Singleton** pattern if you only wish to have one instance of Login class.